# Using a variable in UPDATE statement in Execute SQL Task SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

there are many answered questions about this, but I cannot get it to work.

I have a very simple SQL table (ChangeTrackingTokens) with only 2 columns:

- name (nvarchar(50))
- token nvarchar(100))

In my SSIS package I need to fetch current datetime and update a record in this SQL table with the value.

I created a variable in the package (`CurrentDateTime`) and set it to `GETUTCDATE()`.
I use Execute SQL Task in SSIS and my SQL statement is:

> update changeTrackingTokens set token = ? where name =
> 'SomeTokenName'

In the Parameter Mapping I have the following:

[image]

When I run the package, the value of the token attribute gets blanked out. I used a breakpoint to examine the value of the CurrentDateTime variable and it's displaying the correct value: `07/25/2023 12:15:50 PM`. However, it just doesn't update my SQL table with the correct value. I triple checked the names and everything looks fine. Here's the general tab of the Execute SQL Task editor:

[image]

When I just hardcode the value right into the SQL statement, it gets updated properly. Could this have something to do with the mismatching data types? If so, shouldn't I just get an error? Instead, it just blanks out the existing value in the table as if my variable (`CurrentDateTime`) is blank, but as I mentioned before it's not.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the datatype of the `CurrentDateTime` variable should've been set to just DATE.